# CSS Nested selector, only select level 2, ignore 1st & 3 and up

Tags: html, css

I've got nested divs/classes. It is nested/looped like this:
row-container, row, row-content, col, col-inner

**Goal:**
I want to only select class "col" on the second level of class "box". And ignore the first and third-and-up.

The cleaned html of it is below. But first the css code that works and then what I would expect.

**Working css:**

```
.box > .row-content > .col > .col-inner > .row-container > .row > .row-content > .col { 
    /* css stuff */ 
}
```

**Expected css 1:** (not working)

```
.box > .row-content:nth-of-type(2) > .col  { 
    /* css stuff */ 
}
```

**Expected css 2:** (not working)

```
.box > .row-content > .row-content > .col  { 
    /* css stuff */ 
}
```

**html code**

```
<div class="box row"> 
    <div class="row-content">
        <div class="col"> <!-- IGNORE THIS COL -->
            <div class="col-inner">
                <div class="row-container">
                    <div class="row"> 
                        <div class="row-content">
                            <div class="col"> <!-- TARGET COL -->
                                <div class="col-inner">
                                    <!-- do stuff -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col"> <!-- TARGET COL -->
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="row-content">
                                        <div class="col"> <!-- IGNORE THIS COL -->
                                            <div class="col-inner">
                                                <!-- do stuff -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col"> <!-- IGNORE THIS COL -->
                                            <div class="col-inner">
                                                <!-- do stuff -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Any help and pointers are welcome!

Comment: 1. Why not giving them another class? 2. Can't do it with just one selector. 3. Simplest would be: `.col .col {...}` `.col .col .col {... : initial}`

Comment: nth-of-type works only with siblings element not nested element ... and > select direct child

Comment: @VXp, 1. I cannot give them another class. It is a looped function in Wordpress (with VisualComposer)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Yeah I was afraid of that.

Comment: since you have a working code, use it ... why trying to optimize? you won't find shorter I guess

Comment: "Working css" is not actually working, at least not with this example. Experiment with the above.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Mostly for the sake of learning. This mega long selector feels like not clean code and I would expect there would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: the html feels like not clean code to start with ;) btw, one of the answer provided a shorter version

Comment: Yeah, the html is not clean indeed. This is abstracted from WordPress > Visual Composer.

For now I'll stick to the long, current working css

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

```
.box .row-container > .row > .row-content > .col {
    /* css stuff */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this one

```
.box .col .col:nth-child(1){
      /*Some CSS*/
 }
 .box .col .col:nth-child(2){
     /*Some CSS*/
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. It also affects third and up.

Answer (score -1):

This should resolve your problem

```
.row > .row-content > .col
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. It also affects third and up (also if I add .box in front)

Comment: Sorry, try with this `.row-container > .row > .row-content > .col`